Which condition implies that $f(s)/s$ is increasing?
I'm trying to find a class of functions $f$ that has this property: $f(s)/s$ is increasing in some interval $(0, \lambda)$. The function $f(s)= s^p$ with $p>1$ has this property, for example. My first guess was if convex functions have this property, then I'm trying to manipulate the convexity condition
$$f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq t f(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$
for $t\in [0,1]$ and $x<y$. But I still haven't achieved anything, so my question is whether convexity really implies the property I mentioned.

It is true in this case: Suppose $f$ is convex function with $f(0) = 0$. Then for $s<s'$  if we have $\frac{f(s)}{s}>\frac{f(s')}{s'}$. Let $(1-t)s' = s$. Then $f(s) = f(t\cdot 0 +(1-t)s')\leq t f(0) +(1-t)f(s') = \frac{s}{s'}f(s')$. But this contradicts the choice of $s,s'$. Also, convexity is preserved under adding $+C$, so I think this is true in general.

$f(s)=1$ is convex and $f(s)/s=1/s$ is decreasing.

Similarly $f(s)=s^2 +2$ is convex and $f(s)/s$ is decreasing near s=0$.

@MahammadYusifov Your answer is perfect!

@Ilovemath the example given by Steen82 shows that $f(0) = 0$ is crucial tho for proof to work

I propose a variant of this:

If $f$ is convex and $f<0$ on $(0, \lambda)$, then $\frac{f(s)}{s}$ is increasing.

Let $f$ be convex on $(0, \lambda)$. Let us impose another condition that $f<0$ on $(0, \lambda)$.  Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two points of $(0,\lambda)$. Choose $0<\alpha <x_1$. Then any point (in particular $x_1$) of $(\alpha, x_2)$ can be written as $t\alpha+(1-t)x_2$, for $0<t<1$. Suppose a new function $F$ is defined on $[\alpha, x_2]$ as follows:
$$F(x) = f(x) -f(\alpha).$$
$F(x)$ is also convex on $[\alpha, x_2]$ as
$$F(t\alpha+(1-t)x_2) = f(t\alpha+(1-t)x_2)-f(\alpha) \leq tf(\alpha)+(1-t)f(x_2)-f(\alpha) = tF(\alpha) +(1-t)F(x_1).$$
Further note that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing  if $\frac{F(x)}{x}$ is increasing. This is because if $y_1<y_2$, then $\frac{F(y_1)}{y_1}<\frac{F(y_2)}{y_2}$. Now,
$$\frac{f(y_1)}{y_1}=\frac{F(y_1)+f(\alpha)}{y_1}=\frac{F(y_1)}{y_1}+\frac{f(\alpha)}{y_1}<\frac{F(y_2)}{y_2}+\frac{f(\alpha)}{y_2}=\frac{f(y_2)}{y_2},$$
where we have used the fact that $f<0$.
Let $x_1=t\alpha+(1-t)x_2$. Then
$$\frac{F(x_1)}{x_1} \leq \frac{tF(\alpha)+(1-t)F(x_2)}{x_1}.$$
Thus,
$$\frac{F(x_1)}{x_1} \leq \frac{(1-t)F(x_2)}{x_1},$$
as $F(\alpha)=0$. Now,
$$\frac{1-t}{t\alpha+(1-t)x_2} \leq \frac{1}{x_2}.$$
Thus,
$$\frac{F(x_1)}{x_1}\leq \frac{F(x_2)}{x_2}.$$
Thus, from the previous argument,
$$\frac{f(x_1)}{x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_2)}{x_2}.$$
Thus $\frac{f(s)}{s}$ is increasing.
